# Change variable in component using vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have navbar blade, component with text and another components with page.
It works like I have component with text in navbar, and another component after navbar. That's three another components. How to change text from for example index.vue in text.vue?

That's what I have:

Text.vue:

```
<template>
<p class="title">{{msg}}</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'msg',
        ],
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        mounted() {
        },
        methods: {
        }
    }
</script>
```

Component in navbar.blade.php:

```
    <navbar-title></navbar-title>
```

And I try to change it in index.vue, that should work when we are on this page:

```
data() {
            return {
                msg: 'text',
            }
```

But it doesn't work. How to do it correctly?

EDIT:

```
Vue.component('title', require('./components/Title.vue'));
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you register the vue component?

Comment: @Quezler edited

Answer (score 0):

To pass the message variable from your index.vue through navbar.vue to title.vue each needs to pass the property to the child and each child must pass the property on again all throughout the tree.

Something like this should work for your case: `<title :msg="msg"></title>`

Comment: yes, and i am assuming your `<navbar></navbar>` in your `index.vue` has the `:msg="msg"` as well

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: `index.vue` defines the variable and uses `:msg="msg"` to pass it to your `navbar.vue`, `navbar.vue` needs to have the property since it is receiving it.

Comment: And `navbar.vue` needs to pass the property with `:msg="msg"` to your `title.vue`, which in turn also needs to have the property

Comment: can you show me this on code? I do not know what do u mean

Comment: could you post the content of all the 3 vue files, and then i'll point out what parts need to be changed?

Comment: that's all with this component